# ES6 class and class instance as parameter in constructor

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

class A needs instance of class B.
Should i create B instance inside A constructor, or create instance where class A is initiated and pass instance to A constructor?

Plan A:

```
class A { constructor() { this.b = new B(); } }
```

Plan B:

```
const b = new B();

class A() { 
    constructor(b) { 
        this.b = b; 
    }
}

const a = new A(b);
```

Comment: Ideally, class A should create an instance of class B internally should it require it. Code that consumes class A should not need to know what dependency the class needs

Comment: I would say plan B as it will be useful to manage dependency injections

Comment: plan B is much helpfull]

Comment: As stated this is just a matter of opinion. I really depends on how these classes will used. For example, will it ever be useful for the caller of `A` to pass in anything other than `B`? Will they need to interact with `B` at all?

Comment: This question can't really be answered appropriately because you're asking about something where the approach would depend entirely on the context.

Comment: So, please, you can provide examples with different contexts and scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plan A is ok if**

- Class B should not be replaced with class C in a future
- Class B not using some external dependency like ajax or database or something else.

*OR*

- Your application is proof of concept or you are really time limited

**Plan B is good in all other cases.**

It will bring you flexibility to change your A class behavior on the fly, grants more universality, helps with testing by mocking this dependency.

So I would say that plan A is about simplicity, plan B is about flexibility and testing. Choose whatever you need in every current case

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The first strategy is appropriate where both classes have a relationship where they are meaningless without each other in their exact form and the child instances have no special traits that would otherwise make providing them manually have any benefit.

The latter strategy of injecting the dependencies of the class is far more flexible. This is more apparent in a typed language where you are able to clearly define class abstractions or interfaces that describe what an object "looks like" rather than the actual implementation, e.g. with TypeScript:

```
class Process {
  private storage: StorageInterface;

  constructor(storage: StorageInterface) {
    this.storage = storage;
  }
}

interface StorageInterface {
  store(data: any): Promise<void>;
}
```

It's clear here that a `Process` expect an instance of something that provides a function `store` but it doesn't care about what the actual implementation looks like - that is left up to the class implementing `StorageInterface`:

```
class PostgresStorage implements StorageInterface {
  public async store(data: any): Promise<void> {
    // do some postgres query
  }
}

class FilesystemStorage implements StorageInterface {
  public async store(data: any): Promise<void> {
    // store in the filesystem
  }
}
```

Now we have total flexibility over what type of "storage" we want an instance of a `Process` to use rather than it itself managing what storage it is able to use, the ability to create infinite storage types without modifying the rest of the codebase and more clarity over what a `Process` is interacting with.

```
// A process that stores something in a Postgres instance.
const processA: Process = new Process(new PostgresStorage());

// A process that stores something on the filesystem.
const processB: Process = new Process(new FilesystemStorage());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Plan B is definitely the better approach to take because it makes your `class A` more flexible and removes dependencies on how `class B` works.

Answer (score 0):

The OO approach is a bit different in the JS world than in the strongly typed classical languages. Maybe this change of platform is an excellent opportunity to review your mindsets about how to reuse and think more laterally with the composition in mind.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance