# Is bad practice to create instance of class in constructor with new keyword?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I have class in Javascript and need one object in this class from other class. My question is which is better ?

create instance of class out of class definition or create in constructor ?

sample code:

```
const b = new B();

class A {
  // and then use b
}
// or 
class A {
 constructor() {
 const b = new B();
 }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871285/es6-class-and-class-instance-as-parameter-in-constructor/51871510#51871510

Comment: Yes, it's generally bad practice to `new` up dependencies in constructors. But globals are also bad practice. Option 3: pass `b` **into** the constructor, encouraging looser coupling and easier testing.

Comment: both snippets do different things. you cannot compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever class controls the *lifetime* of the other object(s) creates those objects.

In your example, if `A` controls the lifetime of that particular *instance of `B`*, then it is fine to create `B` in the constructor.

However, if another class controls the lifetime of (or owns) the object from `B`, then an instance of `B` should be passed to `A` in the constructor.

The test is simple: the class that is responsible for the lifetime of other objects is responsible for creating those objects.

Answer (score 0):

If they are both classes can you just extend the class you need.

```
class b {}

class a extends b {}
```